# Is there any way or script to open my site only in Chrome browser and not open in any other browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there any way or script to open my site only in Chrome browser and not open in any other browser ?

Comment: What do you mean "open"? If someone googles your site in Firefox and clicks the link, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: simple and sweet - I want my site to just work in chrome browser and for rest browser will display some message like "This site is only work in Chrome browser" (something like this).

Comment: Thanks @Clonkex, May be this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before ask question please google it,
[Php : Finding Chrome and Safari Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272084/php-finding-chrome-and-safari-browsers)

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
if (preg_match('/MSIE/i', $user_agent)) { 
   echo "Internet Explorer";
}elseif (preg_match('/Firefox/i', $user_agent)) { 
   echo "FireFox";
}elseif (strpos( $user_agent, 'Chrome') !== false)
{
    echo "Google Chrome";
}elseif (strpos( $user_agent, 'Safari') !== false)
{
   echo "Safari";
}elseif (preg_match('/Opera/i', $user_agent)) { 
   echo "Opera";
}
```